# K-means for dataset with 10 million observations and k = 40 using packages "weightedKmeans"

Tags: k-means

I am trying to employ K means algorithm on a dataset which has 10 million observations. The unique identifier is a 9 digit US Zipcode and data is collected by a bank on its customers (regarding their credit card, spend, balance, interest, etc). The objective is to cluster those zipcodes together which have similar financial charateristics. I initially had 24 variables which I reduced to 10 by eliminating highly correlated ones. I also randomly sampled the data and selected 270,000 observations. But still k-means wont work in R. The expectation is to have around 40 number of clusters.
My questions:
1)Is it possible to have 40 clusters for K-means in R
2)I tried to use package 'weightedKmeans'and my command was:
ans <- ewkm(data, 40, lambda=1, maxiter=10, delta=0.00001, maxrestart=10)

I have a table of clusters like this:

<- table(ans$cluster)
    1     2     3     4     5     6     7     8     9    10    40 
14610   834  1433  1329 13241  7063 72091 26282   346 66403 58914

Does this mean I have only 11 clusters? Also I cant do a plotcluster(data, ans$cluster). It gives me an error..

Error in eigen(Z, symmetric = TRUE) : infinite or missing values in 'x'
In addition: Warning message:
In sqrt(wmd) : NaNs produced

3) Is there any other way I can have 40 clusters for this data in R?

Comment: Some links, k-means for very large data sets:  http://blog.revolutionanalytics.com/2011/06/kmeans-big-data.html        http://papers.nips.cc/paper/4362-fast-and-accurate-k-means-for-large-datasets.pdf       http://www.bigdatanews.com/profiles/blogs/fast-clustering-algorithms-for-massive-datasets